# Any common mobile device which doesn't support C++ Exceptions

Tags: android, c++, smartphone

Previously Android's NDK didn't support exceptions in C++, but it appears to now. Are there any other common/popular mobile (smartphone/tablet) devices which don't support exceptions?  I want to build a cross-platform C++ framework and need to know this will work.

Comment: Can the down/close votes please be explained? I don't see how this isn't a valid question.

Comment: It's poll-ish kind of question.

Comment: It's not a poll. I'm not asking for an opinion, I'm asking for facts about the support of C++ in common mobile devices, on the assumption that there are few, to none, which don't support it.

Comment: Mhm, maybe more explicit description will do: it's "do-my-google-for-me-and-make-me-a-list-I-should-be-able-to-do-by-myself"-ish kind of question.

Comment: @t0mm13b, answers can be factual. It's not like one can have an "opinion" about whether a smartphone SDK supports exceptions.  About the answer rate, not all my questions have a correct answer, so I see no reason to accept one just to get my rate up.

Comment: Commenting since I can't answer anymore. Symbian C++ was defined at a time when exceptions had not yet been added to the official C++ standard (at least that's what they told new employees). That is obviously not a problem anymore with the fairly recent phones that support the Qt runtime. However, early Symbian phones (anything before UIQ3 and Series60 5th edition, I believe) used a toolchain specifically configured to prevent the use of C++ exception in order to decrease binary size.